# Firewall requests that think you're another host

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, iptables, ip, vps

I'm a bit of a noob so bear with me.

I routinely check my logs for fun and I got many (thousands) of these errors: http://pastebin.com/i0iSKDCW

The server I'm having problems with is a Burst.net VPS and I'm wondering if I've been allocated someone else's old IP and they left their domain configured or somesuch?

What I want to do, is use iptables or somesuch to deny all requests like this (with the host: eciou.net) without letting them get to Nginx (I have some slow software running underneath Nginx).

**Solution**

As suggested by the wonderful people below, I simply added this to my configuration file:

server {
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  eciou.net;
        location / {
            root /srv/http/static/eciou;
            index index.html;
        }
    }

Note that the [::]:80 is because my server is also set up to accept IPv6. Normally I believe  just 80 would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you most likely got an IP that was used before to host the *eciou.net* domain.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to filter such requests with **iptables**, because it is running on a lower OSI model level and it doesn't know anything about the *Host: ...* HTTP header.

You can filter such requests in *nginx* and prevent them from reaching your heavy software. This can by done by using the $host environment variable: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24host

Here is a quick example that will return 404 for requests to this domain:

```
if ($host ~* "eciou.net") {
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: would be better to used server block for it so that it runs during the normal host comparison instead of doing an additional check for each request.

Comment: Makes sense, indeed.

Comment: So where exactly do you suggest I put it?

Comment: And thanks for the amazing and fast response too ^.^

Comment: Well, like Martin F suggested, there's a better solution than the above example. Simply define a new virtual host for *eciou.net* and point it to an empty directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest returning 404 for all these requests, because.. well, because 404 means "Not Found" and that's really happening here.

E.g.:

```
server {
  listen 80; # only port means "listen all interfaces"
  server_name eciou.net;
  log_not_found off; # if you do not want to log all these 404's
  root /srv/http/static/eciou;
  location / {}
}
```

In this setup, Nginx will search the filesystem for the files requested. Not a big deal, but if you are concerned, `return 404` will be more effective (instead of `root` + `location`)

Comment: That's basically all I did :)

Comment: I outlined 2 variants, you cannot do both of them at the same time.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I pointed it at an empty directory :)